# Using parameters to query in SOQL snap in Snaplogic

Tags: soql, snaplogic

In snaplogic I need to make several SOQL queries and pass the data through to an output.
I would like to reuse a pipeline by using parameters like this in my SOQL snap:

```
"Select " + _columnList + " From " + _tableName
```

I want to then have an .expr file where I would have all the tablenames and column names like this:

{
"table1":    "t1column1", "t1column2", .....
}
{
"table2":  "t2column1", "t2column2", .....
}

I tried adding the expr file to the parameters with an alias of 'sql' then I defined the variable columnList to the value lib.sql.table1. and set a variable for _tablename with the value of the actual table name.

I get an error and it appears the value isn't being translated in the error message I see select _columnList from ....

I want to be able to reuse the pipeline and configure all the table's and columns in the expression library.

Please help me configure this correctly.